# Ensure that all Manual Renewal orders with WooCommerce Subscriptions & WooCommerce Payments are automatically 'Completed'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I've built a website using WooCommerce Subscriptions, which uses WooCommerce Payments as the payment gateway. Users have the options to subscribe on either a monthly or an annual basis. All subscriptions come with a free month's trial.

Currently, subscribers are only able to pay using a credit/debit card. For these users, their subscription is temporarily 'on-hold' until the order completes and when the order completes, the subscription returns to the 'active' status.

However, a select few subscribers have been given a 100% discount voucher. For these, they are marked as 'Via Manual Renewal'. When either parent or renewal orders are created, tthey fail to be marked as 'completed'. They are always left as 'pending'. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that these are 'Manual Renewal' orders.

I've tried to create some PHP code to add in as a snippet, to catch when these users have orders created, so that they can automatically be marked as 'completed'. This is what I have put together so far.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'sd_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function sd_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}

add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'subscription_payment_complete_hook_callback', 10, 1);
function subscription_payment_complete_hook_callback( $subscription ) {
    // Get the current order
    $current_order = $subscription->get_last_order( 'all', 'any' );

    // For Paypal recurring orders
    if( $current_order->get_payment_method() === 'woocommerce_payments' ) {

        // Update status to completed
        $current_order->update_status('completed');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have an effect, in that I still have to manually mark these users' orders as 'complete'.

Can someone please help me identify the issue with the code I've created, and how I might be able to update it, so that I can ensure all manual renewal orders are marked as 'completed' automatically? Or alternatively, is there a way to change Manual Renewal orders, so that they don't need to constantly generate orders?

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, IIRC, if an order has a total of zero, it's status will automatically go the `processing` status. Is the discount applied in some way that WooCommerce is unaware, or the order total is not zero?

Comment: Hey @Caleb, I wondered about that. The discount is basically applied with a coupon and I wonder if that's why? For these ones in particular, the order total is zero but for some reason, they've been marked as 'Manual Renewal'...

Comment: If it’s using WooCommerce coupons, then WC would know about it. Are the renewal orders also zero? If the coupon does not apply to the renewal orders, then this could make sense: if no payment information is collected with the initial order (because order total is zero), then the renewal orders can’t be automatic, because there’s no payment info.

Comment: @Caleb You might have hit the nail on the head there. These orders were created with zero for both the parent and recurring orders. Maybe that's the issue, as no card details would have been taken for a £0 order. Is there a way round it? Can you maybe think of a modification to my PHP code, to essentially catch these orders and mark them as complete?

Comment: Hmm, if the recurring orders are also free, then I would expect them to have been automatic. What did WooCommerce support say?

Comment: Well so far, they said they're going away to look into it and have not actually got back to me.  I'll have to chase them, but I thought I'd give them another day or so. One thing they did say was that I should ensure the products are both downloadable and virtual.

Comment: It certainly seems possible that WooCommerce did not consider subscriptions being free, and the automatic renewal is dependent on a recurring payment being setup within the payment processor. You may very well be the first to want free subscriptions to renew automatically.

Comment: Fair point mate! I'll see what I can work out then going forward and if I come up with something, I'll add it as an answer to my original question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, it was a lot simpler than I thought.

Basically, with WooCommerce, the fact that an order was 'via Manual Renewal' was irrelevant to orders not automatically being marked as 'Completed'.

Essentially, for an order to be marked as 'Completed' automatically, WooCommerce needs to know that no action needs to be taken on behalf of the site owner/admin, once a payment has been received successfully.

Therefore, any product created must be marked as both 'Virtual' and 'Downloadable'. My products were marked as 'Virtual' only, which was why it was happening. Now that they're marked as both, all my orders seem to have been marked as 'Completed' automatically now. :)